# How to pass instance ID as argument in property validator in Python?

Tags: python, validation, google-app-engine

I have an ndb.Model class and inside it there is a particular attribute that calls a certain function as validator:

```
class Article(ndb.Model):
    itemList = ndb.StringProperty()
    ...
    penInspc = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0, indexed=True, validator=minPen)
```

I want the function minPen() to print the ID of the instance of class Article. How do I do that?

Comment: Only the property itself and the value are passed to validator's `minPen` so you don't have access to any other properties of the entity, including `key`. You may wanna look at `_pre_put_hook` which will give you access to the key (if there is one) and where you may raise an exception if necessary.

Comment: I would not tend to use validators unless you really have to ensure a correct datatype.  The problem with validators is if you chnage your requirements and the old data doesn't match you validation requirements you can't load the data.  Use your save() method to perform high level validation and printing etc, and leave validators for low level stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a hook before put. This is as effective as a validator but also won’t mess up your queries in case you don’t have old data that do not respect the new validator rules.

Comment: Why would validators mess up queries?

Comment: A validation will generate an error when fetching old data (written before validator) that do not respect the validator’s rules.